# Neo4j incremental backup strategy

Tags: neo4j

Re-posting from the Google Group.
We are currently keeping 7 backup folders, one per day of the week.
Every midnight, a cron job flushes a given day's backup folder contents and starts fresh with a full then incremental backups (taken once per minute).
At issue is a use case in which a server may be down when it crosses a day boundary, in which case the next days backup folder contents are not purged.
The behavior is that an incremental backup just runs against the old stale data - seemingly without problems.  My reading of the Backup documentation indicates
that the transactions applied during an incremental are based on the accrued transactions from the production data, which is completely decoupled from the backup set
that the transactions are applied to (i.e. our stale data).

So, what reliable test can we do prior to performing a first incremental backup after SOD to see if the folder we're pointing at has stale data in it?  There are some obvious things like log file dates etc., but I thought that I'd post this to see if there is a definitive way to detect a datestamp buried somewhere in the backup folders data that we can rely on.

Thanks, Eric.

Answer (score 1):

A way to go about this is to compare the modification/creation timestamp on the `neostore` file from your weekly backup directory to the one from the previous day. This file is guaranteed to always exist in a complete Neo4j backup so it should be safe to check. If the timestamp for the current day is older than the one before, then obviously you have a stale backup and you can take appropriate action.

A way to compare timestamps on unix-like operating systems you can find here: https://superuser.com/questions/138270/compare-file-timestamp-in-bash

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. We'll give this solution a try.